# R & quosures - How to get names of symbols contained in a vector passed as function argument?

Tags: r, quosure

I want to write an R function `arg2str` that returns the names (that is a vector of strings) of the symbols that are fed as arguments.

For the most simple case, I only have one input symbol:

```
library ("rlang")

arg2str.v0 <- function (arg) rlang::quo_name (enquo (arg))
arg2str.v0 (a)
## [1] "a"
```

If I have multiple symbols, I can use the three-dots construct:

```
arg2str.v1 <- function (...) sapply (enquos (...), rlang::quo_name)
arg2str.v1 (a, b, c)
##             
## "a" "b" "c"
```

(Subsidiary question: why is the resulting vector of strings displayed with a preliminary line break instead of a preliminary `[1]` in this case?)

But I actually want to deal with vectors of symbols. Yet:

```
sym2str.v1 (c(a, b, c))
##
## "c(a, b, c)"
```

How do I tune my function to do so?

---

My first intuition was to first enquote the symbols contained in the argument vector by using `sapply` (instead of enquoting the argument vector itself), then to apply `rlang::quo_name` to the resulting vector of quosures. But it seems that the symbols in the argument vector are evaluated within `sapply` before `enquote` is called on each of them:

```
arg2str.v2 <- function (args) {
    enquo_args <- sapply (args, enquo)
    lapply (enquo_args, rlang::quo_name)
}
arg2str.v2 (c (a, b, c))
## Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : object 'a' not found
```

Comment: Try this : `arg2str.v0 <- Vectorize(arg2str.v0)`,  hope it can help you.

Comment: have you tried your code? @MrSmithGoesToWashington

Comment: Of course I did.

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington, I get a similar error with the vectorized version of `arg2str.v0`, that is: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'a' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible hacky answer using `substitute` and `deparse`:

```
arg2str.v3 <- function (args) {
    strs <- sapply (substitute (args), deparse)
    if (length (strs) > 1) { strs <- strs [-1] }
    return (strs)
}
arg2str.v3 (c (a, b, c))
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Note that it also preserves names if a named vector is provided as input:

```
arg2str.v3 (c (n1 = a, n2 = b, n3 = c))
##  n1  n2  n3 
## "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using rlang conventions, this should work:

```
return_args <- function(args){

    args_expr <- enexpr(args)

    if(length(args_expr) == 1) {
        args_vars <- as.list(args_expr)
    } else {
        args_vars <- as.list(args_expr)[-1]
    }

    sapply(args_vars, quo_name)
}


return_args(c(a, b, c))
[1] "a" "b" "c"

return_args(a)
[1] "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a vectorised tidyeval operation for what you want. You can try

```
f <- function(v) {
    v <- rlang::quo_name(enquo(v))
    gsub('^c\\(|\\s|\\)$', '', v) %>% 
        strsplit(',') %>% 
        unlist 
}

f(c(a, b, c))
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

which will work with inputs of the form `a`, `c(a)` or `c(a, b)` but it's a bit hacky...

The answer to your side question (why `arg2str.v1(a, b, c)` does not print the `"[1]"` at the beginning of the line) is that it returns a named vector, whose names are empty strings (compare e.g. with the output of `set_names(c('a', 'b', 'c'), c('', '', ''))`).

Comment: Hacky indeed, but it does work! Yet, it does not allow named vectors as inputs, e.g. `f(c(n1=a, n2=b))` (additional feature that I did not specify in my question). I guess one could come up with a regular expression to get and preserve such names.

Comment: And thanks also for your answer to the side question. It makes a lot of sense!